# Need row highlighted in table

Tags: javascript

I need to write a function (or building onto code below) that will highlight a specific row in a table. It needs to always ignore the table headers so start a row count of 0 after table headers.

```
<style type="text/css">
#myTbl {
     border: 1px solid black
}
#myTbl td, th {
     border: 1px solid black
}

#myTbl tr.normal td {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}
#myTbl tr.highlighted td {
    color: white;
    background-color: gray;
}
</style>

  <table id="myTbl">
     <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>CreatedDate</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Colour</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>DFRF</td>
        <td>05/03/2010</td>
        <td>Lamp</td>
        <td>Blue</td>
      </tr>
Ect...  
    </tbody>
  </table>

<script type="text/javascript">
var table = document.getElementById("myTbl");
var thead = table.getElementsByTagName("thead")[0];
var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];

tbody.onclick = function (e) {
   e = e || window.event;
   var td = e.target || e.srcElement; 
//so must be no other elements inside the td
   var row = td.parentNode;
    alert('Row is ' + (row.rowIndex - 1))
   if (this.lst&&this.lst!=row){
    this.lst.className='';
   }
   row.className = row.className==="highlighted" ? "" : "highlighted";
   this.lst=row;
}

thead.onclick = function (e) {
   e = e || window.event;
   var th = e.target || e.srcElement;  
//so must be no other elements in the th
   alert(th.innerHTML);
}
</script>
```

Something like

```
function goToRow('2')
```

To select row 2.

Need help please

Comment: There are plenty of sites out there that teach you how to do this. Like this one : http://www.netmechanic.com/news/vol4/javascript_no20.htm
This answer may also be useful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661070/highlight-table-row?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the count as the ID for each TR.
See below:

```
  <table id="myTbl">
     <thead>
      <tr id="tr0">
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>CreatedDate</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Colour</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="tr1">
        <td>DFRF</td>
        <td>05/03/2010</td>
        <td>Lamp</td>
        <td>Blue</td>
      </tr>
```

Then use this JavaScript:

```
function goToRow(where)
{
 document.getElementById("tr"+where+"").style.color="white";
 document.getElementById("tr"+where+"").style.backgroundColor="gray";
}
```

Hope that helps